# How to align a <ul> in a <span> at top?

Tags: html, css, button

I want to make a bookmark page, but, the `<ul>` inside my `<span>` always stays at the bottom and left. I don't know how to place it in the middle (like `valign=center` and `align=center` of the `span`. I've search and experimented but cannot find an answer.

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Google Sans";
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  /*margin-left: 20%;*/
  /*margin-right: 50%;*/
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(129, 129, 233);
}


/*li a {
 display: block;
 color: rgb(144, 144, 248);
 padding: 8px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 
}*/

#buttons li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(98, 204, 88);
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
}

#buttons li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #33B5E5;
}


/*li a:hover {
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
 border: 60px gray;
}*/

span {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}

span ul {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: 10px;
}

#buttons li a:hover .hypixel {
  background-color: rgb(197, 172, 58);
}
```

```html
<!--
  <li><a href="https://"></a></li>   
-->
  <span>
    <ul id="buttons">
      <li>Programming</li>
      <li><a href="https://codeforces.com">Codeforces</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://vnoi.info">VNOI</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://vnoi.info/wiki/Home">VNOI Wiki</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xSPwkmXcGotPTO4hrbBRwyxngxgOEXpJCCRWJEq04BI/edit#gid=0">Tài liệu lập trình</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.mediafire.com/folder/9jm64z3or98au/C_C%2B%2B">C C++</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kohr6pMwag&list=PL33lvabfss1wUj15ea6W0A-TtDOrWWSRK">C# Kteam</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://cspcope.tk/Problem"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </span>
  <span>
    <ul id="buttons">
      <li>Minecraft</li>
      <li><a href="https://minecraft.tools/en/">Minecraft Tools</a></li>
      <li><a class="hypixel" href="https://hypixel.net">Hypixel</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://minecraft.net">Official Minecraft Site</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://aternos.org/server/">MCPC 2</a></li>
      <li><a href=""></a></li>
      <li><a href=""></a></li>

    </ul>
  </span>
  <span>
    <ul id="buttons">
      <li>Phim và giải trí</li>
      <li><a href="https://www.fshare.vn/folder/ICWBG4Y927K1#!#94u203z203r2t2e47413z2e4u25423">Phim Việt</a></li>

    </ul>
  </span>
  <span></span>
```

Where had I done wrong?

And also, the .hypixel class won't be yellow when I hover over it.

Comment: The `ul`, being a block level element. is not allowed as a child of a `span`, being an inline element. Furthermore, you can't have anything other than `tbody/thead/tr` as children of the `table`. Your HTML here have heavy syntax errors, so you need to start with read up on that before worrying about the CSS

Comment: Also your HTML is invalid. In addition to ^, a `<span>` can't be a child of a `<table>` element

Comment: I've remove my `<table>` but the last `<span>` still stay at the bottom, it won't be in the middle

Comment: Your table is missing `<tr><td>` elements. Review your html code.

Comment: I've remove my `<table>` but the last `<span>` still stay at the bottom, it won't be in the middle. It's also still left-aligned and idk how to put it in the middle of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution in CSS:

```
.bookmark {
  position: relative;
}
.bookmark ul {
  position: absolute;
  top 0;
}
```

HTML: placed the class on the outer span elements

```
<html>
    <head></head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Bookmarks</title>
    <body>
        <!--
                <li><a href="https://"></a></li>            
        -->
        <table>
                <span class="bookmark">
                    <ul id="buttons">
                        <li>Programming</li>
                        <li><a href="https://codeforces.com">Codeforces</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://vnoi.info">VNOI</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://vnoi.info/wiki/Home">VNOI Wiki</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xSPwkmXcGotPTO4hrbBRwyxngxgOEXpJCCRWJEq04BI/edit#gid=0">Tài liệu lập trình</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.mediafire.com/folder/9jm64z3or98au/C_C%2B%2B">C C++</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kohr6pMwag&list=PL33lvabfss1wUj15ea6W0A-TtDOrWWSRK">C# Kteam</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://cspcope.tk/Problem"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
                <span class="bookmark">
                    <ul id="buttons">
                        <li>Minecraft</li>
                        <li><a href="https://minecraft.tools/en/">Minecraft Tools</a></li>
                        <li><a class="hypixel" href="https://hypixel.net">Hypixel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://minecraft.net">Official Minecraft Site</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://aternos.org/server/">MCPC 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href=""></a></li>
                        <li><a href=""></a></li>

                    </ul>
                </span>
                <span class="bookmark">
                    <ul id="buttons">
                        <li>Phim và giải trí</li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.fshare.vn/folder/ICWBG4Y927K1#!#94u203z203r2t2e47413z2e4u25423">Phim Việt</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </span>
            <span></span>
</html>
```

But everyone else's complaints are valid. You need to validate your HTML and spend more time thinking about *why* you pick the tags you do. `Table` the nested `spans` and `ul`? That's not smart or necessary.

I would do this like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Bookmarks</title>
     </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
          <div class="bookmark">
            <ul id="buttons">
              <li>Programming</li>
              <li><a href="https://codeforces.com">Codeforces</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://vnoi.info">VNOI</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://vnoi.info/wiki/Home">VNOI Wiki</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xSPwkmXcGotPTO4hrbBRwyxngxgOEXpJCCRWJEq04BI/edit#gid=0">Tài liệu lập trình</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.mediafire.com/folder/9jm64z3or98au/C_C%2B%2B">C C++</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kohr6pMwag&list=PL33lvabfss1wUj15ea6W0A-TtDOrWWSRK">C# Kteam</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="bookmark">
            <ul id="buttons">
              <li>Minecraft</li>
              <li><a href="https://minecraft.tools/en/">Minecraft Tools</a></li>
              <li><a class="hypixel" href="https://hypixel.net">Hypixel</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://minecraft.net">Official Minecraft Site</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://aternos.org/server/">MCPC 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="bookmark">
            <ul id="buttons">
              <li>Phim và giải trí</li>
              <li><a href="https://www.fshare.vn/folder/ICWBG4Y927K1#!#94u203z203r2t2e47413z2e4u25423">Phim Việt</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </nav>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `<span>`s because they're invalid and it's discouraged when a table is used for layout so that's removed as well (it wasn't even complete just the starting tag). `<meta>` and `<title>` tags belong in the `<head>` tag. Most importantly **Never duplicate id**. Each `<ul>` had `id="buttons"` change each one to `class="buttons"`.

I am assuming that you want each `<ul>` as a column. I wrapped a `<main>` tag around the three `<ul>` and assigned it [`display: flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to set them side-by-side. `.hypixel` selector needs to be suffix of `<a>`. Also, I don't understand what the last `<ul>` needs to be in the middle of.

---

### Demo

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Google Sans";
}

.flex {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items:start;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(129, 129, 233);
}

.buttons li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(98, 204, 88);
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
}

.buttons li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #33B5E5;
}


/*li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    border: 60px gray;
}*/

span {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: 10px;
}

.buttons li a.hypixel:hover  {
  background-color: rgb(197, 172, 58);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Bookmarks</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main class='flex'>
    <ul class="buttons">
      <li>Programming</li>
      <li><a href="https://codeforces.com">Codeforces</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://vnoi.info">VNOI</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://vnoi.info/wiki/Home">VNOI Wiki</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xSPwkmXcGotPTO4hrbBRwyxngxgOEXpJCCRWJEq04BI/edit#gid=0">Tài liệu lập trình</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.mediafire.com/folder/9jm64z3or98au/C_C%2B%2B">C C++</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kohr6pMwag&list=PL33lvabfss1wUj15ea6W0A-TtDOrWWSRK">C# Kteam</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://cspcope.tk/Problem"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="buttons">
      <li>Minecraft</li>
      <li><a href="https://minecraft.tools/en/">Minecraft Tools</a></li>
      <li><a class="hypixel" href="https://hypixel.net">Hypixel</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://minecraft.net">Official Minecraft Site</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://aternos.org/server/">MCPC 2</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href=""></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""></a>
      </li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="buttons">
      <li>Phim và giải trí</li>
      <li><a href="https://www.fshare.vn/folder/ICWBG4Y927K1#!#94u203z203r2t2e47413z2e4u25423">Phim Việt</a></li>

    </ul>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

Take a look at the changes in the `span` style:

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Google Sans";
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  /*margin-left: 20%;*/
  /*margin-right: 50%;*/
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(129, 129, 233);
}


/*li a {
 display: block;
 color: rgb(144, 144, 248);
 padding: 8px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 
}*/

#buttons li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(98, 204, 88);
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
}

#buttons li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #33B5E5;
}


/*li a:hover {
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
 border: 60px gray;
}*/

span {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

span ul {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: 10px;
}

#buttons li a:hover .hypixel {
  background-color: rgb(197, 172, 58);
}
```

```html
<span>
    <ul id="buttons">
      <li>Programming</li>
      <li><a href="https://codeforces.com">Codeforces</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://vnoi.info">VNOI</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://vnoi.info/wiki/Home">VNOI Wiki</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xSPwkmXcGotPTO4hrbBRwyxngxgOEXpJCCRWJEq04BI/edit#gid=0">Tài liệu lập trình</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.mediafire.com/folder/9jm64z3or98au/C_C%2B%2B">C C++</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kohr6pMwag&list=PL33lvabfss1wUj15ea6W0A-TtDOrWWSRK">C# Kteam</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://cspcope.tk/Problem"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </span>
<span>
    <ul id="buttons">
      <li>Minecraft</li>
      <li><a href="https://minecraft.tools/en/">Minecraft Tools</a></li>
      <li><a class="hypixel" href="https://hypixel.net">Hypixel</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://minecraft.net">Official Minecraft Site</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://aternos.org/server/">MCPC 2</a></li>
      <li><a href=""></a></li>
      <li><a href=""></a></li>
    </ul>
  </span>
<span>
    <ul id="buttons">
      <li>Phim và giải trí</li>
      <li><a href="https://www.fshare.vn/folder/ICWBG4Y927K1#!#94u203z203r2t2e47413z2e4u25423">Phim Việt</a></li>

    </ul>
  </span>
<span></span>
```

Hope this helps,